# using python build, how do I pass --debug through to build command

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, python-wheel

If I run `python3 setupy.py build --debug` I get the results I want where my build is built with `debug`. From the help this executes:

```
  --debug (-g)       compile extensions and libraries with debugging
                     information
```

However using a *PEP 517* install like [build](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), it calls `bdist_wheel` which in turn calls `install` which calls `build`.  I would like a command line way to toggle between *release* and *debug* builds for my underlying *C++* extension.

I had hoped the following would do it:

```
python3 -m build --config-setting=--build-option=--debug
```

However the `bdist_wheel` command rejects the `--debug` flag as unknown.

I can add a `setup.cfg` with the following in it:

```
[build]
debug=1
```

and my build works correctly. I am looking for the command line equivalent.

Comment: Does building the source distribution and wheel separately (`python3 -m build -s -C--build-option=--debug` and `python3 -m build -w`) work?

Comment: @chepner no, I do usually only call the wheel,  the problem is the bdist_weel step doesn't support --debug at all.  Made i need to use another pep517 build/install tool

Comment: this seems to work! python3 setup.py setopt --command build -o debug -s 1